# How to put value of User Defined Variable into Bean shell Sampler Variable - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I try to move a User Defined variable to variable in beanshell sampler.
(I need the User defined variable to be part of a bigger string.)

When I try to move it, or make a copy of it I get error 500

can someone please advise how can I put the value of user defined field in bean-shell variable and than use it (not need to change the user defined variable just want it value)

In this script I Want to put the value of $Expected_Offer_ID  to String variable Expected_Offer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 options:

1. Put `${Expected_Offer_ID}` to "Parameter" section of the Sampler. You will be able to access it as `Parameters` in your script
2. Use `vars.get("Expected_Offer_ID);` where required. `vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables

[image: JMeter Groovy Access Variables]

Remember 2 things:

- **Never** refer [JMeter Variables and/or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the Script body like `${myVar}`, either use aforementioned "Parameters" section or code-based equivalents as they might resolve into something which can cause script interpretation failure or unexpected behaviour. Moreover, in case of [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org) language it prevents compiled scripts caching
- Don't use Beanshell for scripting. Since JMeter 3.1 [it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Groovy is more Java-compliant and performs much better. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more detailed explanation, benchmarks and some tips on Groovy JDK enhancements usage.

Answer (score 3):

JMeter variables are accessed through `vars` object, use:

```
 String Expected_Offer =  vars.get("Expected_Offer");
```

Comment: Thanks it solved it, another issue is Can I use the same for moving value of variable that I extract using regex?  for example if I have a regex that put the response in value res_imp (see pic) can I put the value of res_imp in the same way?

Comment: Yes. It is jmeter variable also